# Postgres SQL undefined symbol : pqsignal

Tags: centos, postgresql

Hi I am trying to install Postgres on my CentOS 7 server. 
Installation was successful, But when I type `psql` I get this error

```
psql: symbol lookup error: psql: undefined symbol: pqsignal
```

I am installing Postgres 12 and it was installed in the folder /usr/pgsql_12/

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same `libpq` library as the one used in psql 12.

The following might help (but verify your true folders):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/pgsql_12/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
sudo /sbin/ldconfig /usr/pgsql_12/lib
```

Comment: This fixed a similar issue I had with a DBeaver issue I had using Postgres 14.2 on Manjaro.